# Show attribute on button click

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am starting with JQuery, sorry for the simple question, I just can´t seem to find an answer. 
There are two HTML links with class "button" and different IDs. When you click on a link, I need it to alert the appropriate ID. However they both alert ID from the first link. How to modify the code so that both links alert their ID?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="button" id = "1"> test1 </a> <br><br>
<a href="#" class="button" id = "2"> test2 </a>
</body>

<script>
$(".button").click(function(){
    alert($(".button").attr("id"));
});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to targeted the clicked button using `this` keyword
`alert($(this).attr("id"));`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="button" id = "1"> test1 </a> <br><br>
<a href="#" class="button" id = "2"> test2 </a>
</body>

<script>
$(".button").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
</script>

</html>
```